# Replace elements of a character vector based on string in R

Tags: r, if-statement, dplyr, grepl

So I have a dataframe like so:

```
Occupation
ELECTRICIAN
ROAD ELECTRICIAN
ELECTRICIAN
FARMER
GRASS ELECTRICIAN
POLE ELECTRICIANS
ELECTRICIAN
INSPECTOR
```

So I would like any time ELECTRICIAN appears to be just ELECTRICIAN, no matter anything else in the cell.

So final product should be:

```
Occupation
ELECTRICIAN
ELECTRICIAN
ELECTRICIAN
FARMER
ELECTRICIAN
ELECTRICIAN
ELECTRICIAN
INSPECTOR
```

I tried the following but this did not work....

```
ifelse(grep('CONDUCTOR',df$Occupation , value=TRUE), "CONDUCTOR",df$Occupation)
```

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest this approach. It is better using `grepl()` as it produces logic values that can be easily detected in `ifelse()`:

```
#Data
df <- structure(list(Occupation = c("ELECTRICIAN", "ROAD ELECTRICIAN", 
"ELECTRICIAN", "FARMER", "GRASS ELECTRICIAN", "POLE ELECTRICIANS", 
"ELECTRICIAN", "INSPECTOR")), row.names = c(NA, -8L), class = "data.frame")
```

Code:

```
#Code
df$Occupation <- ifelse(grepl('ELECTRICIAN',df$Occupation), 'ELECTRICIAN',df$Occupation)
```

Output:

```
   Occupation
1 ELECTRICIAN
2 ELECTRICIAN
3 ELECTRICIAN
4      FARMER
5 ELECTRICIAN
6 ELECTRICIAN
7 ELECTRICIAN
8   INSPECTOR
```

Comment: Since there's not really an "else" case, it can be more succinct and efficient is to use direct assignment instead of `ifelse`: `df$Occupation[grepl("ELECTRICIAN", df$Occupation)] <- "ELECTRICIAN"`.

Comment: @GregorThomas You are right, it is a great suggestion. I just followed the style of the OP question to produce the solution !

Answer (score 2):

Here's the tidyverse solution using the `stringr` package.

```
    library(stringr)      
    df$Occupation<- str_replace_all(df$Occupation,".*ELECTRICIAN.*","ELECTRICIAN")
```

There's some debate over whether tidyverse solutions are "preferred," but I personally prefer them. I think the function names are much more intuitive both for you and whoever may be reading your code. I also think it's concise and direct, doing exactly what you want to do.

Answer (score 1):

Using `grep` you can get the index in `Occupation` where `"ELECTRICIAN"` is present and replace those values.

```
df$Occupation[grep('ELECTRICIAN', df$Occupation)] <- 'ELECTRICIAN'
df

#   Occupation
#1 ELECTRICIAN
#2 ELECTRICIAN
#3 ELECTRICIAN
#4      FARMER
#5 ELECTRICIAN
#6 ELECTRICIAN
#7 ELECTRICIAN
#8   INSPECTOR
```